# Microsoft MessageQueue Formatter property is always null

Tags: c#, .net, ipc, message-queue

I have the following problem with a basic Microsoft Message Queue implementation:

On the reading side the `Formatter` property of the message is always null, no matter what i input on the sending side.

Sending Code:

```
System.Messaging.Message m = new System.Messaging.Message("string to send");
m.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter( new Type[1] { typeof(string) } );
queue.Send(m, "label");
```

Receiving Code:

```
MessageEnumerator enumerator = queue.GetMessageEnumerator2();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Message m = enumerator.RemoveCurrent();
    Console.WriteLine("MSQ: " + m.Label);

    Console.WriteLine("Formatter: " + m.Formatter.GetType().ToString()); // crash because formatter property is null

    Console.WriteLine("Body: " + m.Body); //also crashes since formatter is null
}
```

Since `Formatter` is null i can also not get `m.Body` which is what i need the most.

Comment: But... messages are "deserialized" using the **MessageQueue**.Formatter property, aren't they? If so, do you have initialized the MessageQueue.Formatter property (**queue**.Formatter) in the receiving code?

Comment: @JuanMellado: no i did not. actually i thought this is done automatically since in the doc it says it defaults to XmlMessageFormatter

Comment: Yes, but you still can do `((XmlMessageFormatter)queue.Formatter).TargetTypes = new Type[1] { typeof(string) };` [not tested]

Comment: yep, that works! thanks! if you post it as an answer i can reward you the bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Messages are *deserialized* using the `MessageQueue.Formatter` property. So you must initialize the `MessageQueue.Formatter` property (**queue**.Formatter) in the receiving code:

```
((XmlMessageFormatter)queue.Formatter).TargetTypes = new Type[1] { typeof(string) };
```